# Wrong form input formats in ChromiumWebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, cefsharp

I'm using the ChromiumWebBrowser to load some pages within my WPF application, displaying the pages works well, however the format of the input fields seem to have the wrong format.

the date field is rendered like this: mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy
the time field is rendered like this: 11:00 PM instead of 23:00

The device I'm using is set to nl-NL according to the Language identifiers RFC 3066

Also, I've tried the following (with no success)

```
ChromiumWebBrowser Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser()
Browser.BrowserSettings.AcceptLanguageList = "nl-NL";
Browswer.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("nl-NL");
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you doing to set the format of the date fields?

Comment: and whats in your resx file

Comment: @SimonPrice I'm not doing anything to set the format of the date field, I believe that should happen automatically depending on the browser and OS.

Comment: @SimonPrice Where can I find the resx file?

Comment: if you go to the properties and then resources of the project you would need to handle it all there.  just because you set a language in the system doesn't mean that its going to do everything for you, you need to provide it with that resource, the conversions of the languages the date formats and pretty much everything else other than your default format.